# Trouble with "getContents"

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling to understand if this is a problem or design feature with Prelude's getContents function. Suppose we have the following code, saved in a file named "getContentsTest.hs":

```
main = do
    contents <- getContents
    putStrLn contents
```

If I now (on my Windows 10 system), compile this with

```
ghc getContentsTest.hs
```

and run the resulting executable, the command prompt refuses to acknowledge input. The text cursor still flashes, as if it WANTS to accept input, but typing on my (physical) keyboard produces nothing onscreen. Additionally, issuing CTRL-Z and CTRL-C commands do not stop the program, and I have to close the command prompt in order to stop the program.

However, if I just run

```
runhaskell getContentsTest.hs
```

it works as expected (i.e. it prints your input to the terminal, and the program stops if it encounters an end-of-file signal, such as CTRL-D, or if someone interrupts the program with CTRL-C)

Why does compiling this short program cause the getContents function to behave differently?

**UPDATE:**

I haven't been able to replicate the above behaviour on any other machine, so I feel this must be something specific to the computer I first tried this on. Thus, this is now less of a Haskell specific question, and more of a "Why isn't the Windows command prompt behaving as it should" sort of question.

The key (mis)behaviour of the machine I'm using is that when I run the above program, the command prompt essentially freezes, not accepting input. Thus, thank you for the insights into getContents, but I feel this problem is something specific to my PC that I need to resolve myself.

Comment: This is due to lazy IO - I would expect that if you run this program, input a bunch of text, then kill it with Ctrl+C, you would see nothing because it reads the contents lazily (and putStrLn consumes them lazily) and killing the program with Ctrl+C makes *no guarantees* about what happens with buffered data. The fact that the interpreter actually *does* write this data is irrelevant - it is undefined behavior. However, I cannot reproduce the same behaviour with Ctrl+Z: ending the program with Ctrl+Z correctly prints the entire input in either case in my tests.

Comment: @user2407038, this is *not* related to lazy `IO` at all. `putStrLn` will pull steadily from its argument to allow it to produce output and stop when it hits `""`. `getContents` will yield characters (lazily) until it reaches the end of its input (achieved with `^Z`) and then produce that final `""`. As Thomas M. DuBuisson's answer indicates, the problem here is that the OP is using the wrong buffering mode for their purpose--something that could easily be encountered in a strict language as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was discovered that this is a problem with a specific computer, and not related to the title or tags

Comment: @luqui I can just delete the question - is that appropriate?

Comment: You cannot delete a question with answers unilaterally unless you're a moderator. You're not a moderator. Also, the question may prove to be useful to someone else encountering a similar issue with the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This question is sort of an FAQ - or the root cause is.

stdin and stdout are line buffered so you won't see anything until that buffer is filled or a newline.  You can turn off buffering for behavior that might be more inline with your expectations using `hSetBuffering`:

```
import System.IO
main =
 do hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    getContents >>= putStrLn
```

With an end behavior of:

```
hheellllooww  wwoorrlldd
```

(yes, I typed 'hello world')

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I think the issue I'm having is separate and unrelated (running the above example freezes as before). I have edited my question, as I have been unable to replicate the original problem on any other machine, and I feel my original problem must be something specific to my Windows installation. Thank you for your explanation anyway!